# Filestream with nHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, filestream

I know the older version(s) of nHiberate at first did not support MS SQL varbinary w/Filestream enabled; however, in their more recent documentation they noted that support for it was added. I cannot find any examples of how to use it. Does anyone have any examples of how to implement this?

update: I am using "fluent" nhib**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Persisting Blob Streams with NHibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498712/persisting-blob-streams-with-nhibernate)

Comment: I've posted an answer on another question http://stackoverflow.com/a/33636478/2690296

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean? NHibernate does not know if FILESTREAM is enabled or not, this a SQL Server internal thing... You just have to set the property type in your mapping as BinaryBlob.